# C# Regular Expression not matching

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression

```
 string dateformattwo = @"^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)(?:0?2|(?:Feb))\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})";
```

and two strings

```
string value = "30.Jul.2019 This is the line that I want to match"
string value2 = "30.jul.2019"
```

The regex is correct however it does not match with value but it matches with value2. Why is that happening?

Comment: Your regex doesn't match either of the samples you provided, according to RegexBuddy.

Comment: Same with Regex101, no matches. What's this regex trying to do? It seems awfully specific - perhaps there's an easier way to do it.

Comment: Okay My bad, I made a mistake @NickReed and Ken, value2 is actually equal to "30.Jul.2019"

Comment: Ah! That DOES return a match, thank you. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @KevoyWalters see edited answer below, looks like the `$` is causing an issue. If your regex is preceded by `^` and followed by `$`, it will **only** match if the desired expression has no characters before or after it on that line.

Comment: It still doesnt match the first one for me

Comment: I am checking to see if I have anything missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>[I couldn't get your regex to match your strings,](https://regex101.com/r/v9iET4/1) so it's hard to say exactly what's expected here, but I can take a guess as to why it's not working: nowhere in your regex are you looking for `july` - looks to me like you're only matching for `JUL`.</s>

Edit: each of your regexes end with `$`, which asserts its position at the end of the line. Your first line fails because there's characters after the date.

[Updates regex here](https://regex101.com/r/v9iET4/2) which, despite being a php-matching regex as pointed out in the comments, still matches your desired text.

Comment: I made a mistake with the question. value2 = "30.Jul.2019"

Comment: Nck, One more thing

Comment: I have a next regex where it matches a time. So if there is a successful match with the date, it then reads the same line and checks if there is a match with the time.

Comment: The same line is: 30.Jul.2019 This the line I want to match 15:04:09
The regex is "^([0-1]?\d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?\d))?(?::([0-5]?\d))?" Could you check if its working properly?

Comment: You'd either have to edit your question, post a new one, or go to chat. To help, you'd also need the regex / code you've tried, the result, and the expected behavior. Can't really do that from the comments, and the mods would probably get mad if we did. Let me know what you decide.

Comment: I upload a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226263/c-sharp-regex-to-match-time