# C# Regex to match time

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a Regex to match the "time" (`hh:mm:ss`) for example `11:20:00`, `18:02:22` or `6:00:00` .

I wrote the following but it does not work as expected.
It matches when its the only thing in the string or if its the first value in the string.
For example:

```
string timepattern = @"^([0-1]?\d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?\d))?(?::([0-5]?\d))?";
string value = "30.Jul.2019 This the line I want to match 15:04:09"
var returnedValue = Regex.Match(line, timepattern);
```

`returnedValue` would yield `3`. But I want the whole time.

Comment: ^ means it must be in the beginning of the string.

Comment: This didnt work

Comment: It still only matched "3"

Comment: \d{,2}\:\d{,2}\:\d{,2}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for matching HH:MM time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536755/regular-expression-for-matching-hhmm-time-format) or of [Regex pattern for HH:MM:SS time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318236/regex-pattern-for-hhmmss-time-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    string timepattern = @"(?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9])[:.][0-5]?[0-9][:.][0-5]?[0-9]";
    string value = "30.Jul.2019 This the line I want to match 15:04:09";
    var returnedValue = Regex.Match(value, timepattern);
```

I use the following web site to lookup regexs, it may be useful for you...

http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=time+hh%3amm%3ass&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20

Another nice information source, 
https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the time and don't care about the rest of the line, it's `([0-1]?\d|2[0-3]):(?:([0-5]?\d))?:(?:([0-5]?\d))?`

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/QWFTEF/2)